# cordova_plugins.js is not updated after adding new plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I just started using cordova with android.

I have a problem when adding plugins.

I used cordova plugin to add org.apache.cordova.camera from cmd in Win7.
It is added but not in cordova_plugins.js file.

File is getting updated when I type cordova run android this in cmd but then all my code is deleted and replaced with skeletal web-based application. Why is this happening? How to automatically get this file updated?

This is how my cordova_plugins.js looks like:

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = [
    {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.dialogs/www/notification.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.dialogs.notification",
        "merges": [
            "navigator.notification"
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.dialogs/www/android/notification.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.dialogs.notification_android",
        "merges": [
            "navigator.notification"
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.vibration/www/vibration.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.vibration.notification",
        "merges": [
            "navigator.notification"
        ]
    }
];
module.exports.metadata = 
// TOP OF METADATA
{
    "org.apache.cordova.dialogs": "0.2.5",
    "org.apache.cordova.vibration": "0.3.6"
}
// BOTTOM OF METADATA
});
```

As you can see there is no camera plugin. It is added in my project, but not in this file and that's reason it is not working when I try to use it in my js files.

I hope you understood what I am saying.

Answer (score 1):

Does it show up in the list when you type:

```
cordova plugin ls
```

Did you rerun:

```
cordova build wp7
```

Comment: Don't know if it worked for the OP but I was having the same problem for Android and 'cordova build android' updated the plugins in the www folder and cordova_plugins.js file.

Comment: I have same problem with camera plugin not added to cordova_plugins.js. I check my plugins with `phonegap plugin list`,  there are two of my plugin not added in cordova_plugins.js, `camera` and `dialogs`. So i remove then add again `dialog`, and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

> - Delete ./platforms [or move to some other place as a backup]
> - Delete ./plugins [or move to some other place as a backup]
> - Build e.g: `ionic cordova build android --prod` or `ionic cordova prepare`
> - This resets everything, fetches FRESH plugins from config.xml

PS: add/remove/update versions of plugins and packages from `package.json` and run `npm i` beforehand.

You might need to update config.xml with the right versions too (if you are trying to fix a version conflict)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with another plugin, and I did the old and magic trick: I restarted Windows (Windows 7)

After restart Windows I did the following steps:

- Removed all plugins (I don't know if it is necessary to remove all)
- Removed cordova_plugins.js
- I executed platforms/android/cordova/clean.bat
- Mi plugin had a dependency (Inappbrowser), so I installed Inappbrowser first.
- I installed the plugin

I don't know if all these steps are necessary, maybe just works restarting Windows. However, it worked for me.